# Using multiple AND in nested IF

Tags: excel, syntax, excel-formula

I want a nested IF, and in seperate IF's I want to be able to use the AND function.

I have 7 different cells I need to check, so I'm getting pretty lost, what I have so far is:

```
=IF(G1="yes";"Result 1";(IF(AND(A1>=3;A1<=4),AND(B1>=800;B1<=1200),AND(C1>=1300;C1<=1400),AND(D1>=80;D1<=90),AND(E1>=100;E1<=120),AND(F1>=45;F1<=60);"Result 2"))
```

However this function doesn't work, I'd like to know where I went wrong, and if there's a shorter solution, because this seems like a formula that's way too long.

Comment: Do you want it to say Result 2 if *any* of those conditions are true or if *all* of them are?

Comment: Changing your `;` into `,` should solve your problem.

Comment: "The function doesn't work..." - how doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Does it run, but return an incorrect result, etc.?

Comment: @newacc2240 Semicolons are used instead of commas for some non-English versions of Excel. Occasionally, you will see a question here on SO that uses semicolons.

Comment: However I've seen several posts were solved after replacing semicolons with commas :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you want something like this ...

```
if
    G = yes     
then
    Result 1    
else
    if  A between 3 and 4
    and B between 800 and 1200
    and C between 1300 and 1400
    and D between 80 and 90
    and E between 100 and 120
    and F between 45 and 60
    then
        Result 2
    else ???    
        ???
    endif
endif
```

You don't need to nest and bracket the various AND's , as

```
And(A, And(B, C)) == And(A, B, C)
```

therefore you could write

```
=IF(G1="yes";"Result 1";IF(AND(A1>=3;A1<=4;B1>=800;B1<=1200;C1>=1300;C1<=1400;D1>=80;D1<=90;E1>=100;E1<=120;F1>=45;F1<=60);"Result 2"))
```

and you should think of a "Result 3" if any of the "between" parts don't draw ... otherwise you just get a "FALSE" ... this is not a "not working" ... just a "badly thought" *ggg*

PLUS

you have a wild mixture of `";"` and `","` as seperators in your formula ... depending on the language it should be only one

I am using German, so all is `";"` ... you may need to change all to `","` if you use English